# Amazon libs3 (environment variables)

Tags: amazon-s3

```
Missing environment variable: S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

is the error I am getting even after assigning it. I used aws configure command in which I inserted the environment variables. But while listing, I get this error. What should I do??.
COMMAND LINE::

```
$ export S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=************
$ s3 list
Missing environment variable: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Comment: You should post errors etc in the answer as text, not as an image. And is that some secret keys you have just posted???? Ooops

Comment: DO NOT PUT your access keys on internet (even if from a picture) anyone can steal it from you

Comment: Thank you for the concerns. The keys has been  deleted from the account earlier before posting.

Comment: @AayushiGupta Please update the question with the screen output AS TEXT.

Comment: Please don't edit questions in such a ways as they change the meaning. It is good to see that you have included the relevant information as text, not an image, but the text is not what you originally posted. If you have managed to move on from the original error, you could either post a new questions to on, or in this case update the question with the next set of errors. The thing is though, if you read the error you got, it is the same problem, that the name of the variable you exported is not the name that is required.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the environment variable is wrong.
You set:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
```

but it is looking for `S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID`:

```
$ s3 list
Missing environment variable: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

What is possibly more interesting however, is that you did use `aws configure` in the first place, although this is not shown in recent edits, only in the images in original post. We would expect `aws configure` to correctly set the environment. And we would also expect the variables to be named `AWS_*` not `S3_*`. So why is `s3 list` looking for `S3_*`?

I can't find any reference to `s3 list`. Are you sure this is the correct command. Do you actually want to use something like: `aws s3 ls` ?

Comment: How to set for S3 then?? Basically, we are trying to access S3 through LibS3 from terminal and we need to set environment variables ,how to set them?

Comment: Please read the answer. You have set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`. It should be `S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Answer (score 1):

For newbie to AWS, read  [AWS CLI getting started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) documentation.

The recommended way for AWS cli is using  `aws configure` to setup your credential and environment. If you insists to setup env variable manually, you need to make 3 export. (key shown are example shown from AWS CLI documentation)

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```